# Pandas use variable for column names part 2

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Given the following data frame:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3],
                   'B':[4,5,6],
                   'C':[7,8,9],
                   'D':[1,3,5],
                   'E':[5,3,6],
                   'F':[7,4,3]})

df

    A   B   C   D   E   F
0   1   4   7   1   5   7
1   2   5   8   3   3   4
2   3   6   9   5   6   3
```

How can one assign column names to variables for use in referring to said column names?

For example, if I do this:

```
cols=['A','B']
cols2=['C','D']
```

I then want to do something like this:

```
df[cols,'F',cols2]
```

But the result is this:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you need add column `F` to `list`:

```
allcols = cols + ['F'] + cols2
print df[allcols]
   A  B  F  C  D
0  1  4  7  7  1
1  2  5  4  8  3
2  3  6  3  9  5
```

Or:

```
print df[cols + ['F'] +cols2]
   A  B  F  C  D
0  1  4  7  7  1
1  2  5  4  8  3
2  3  6  3  9  5
```

Answer (score 1):

Need give a `list` with columns for reference.

```
In [48]: df[cols+['F']+cols2]
Out[48]:
   A  B  F  C  D
0  1  4  7  7  1
1  2  5  4  8  3
2  3  6  3  9  5
```

and, consider using `df.loc[:, cols+['F']+cols2]`,  `df.ix[:, cols+['F']+cols2]` for slicing.

Answer (score 1):

Python 3 solution:

```
In [154]: df[[*cols,'F',*cols2]]
Out[154]:
   A  B  F  C  D
0  1  4  7  7  1
1  2  5  4  8  3
2  3  6  3  9  5
```

Comment: Maybe typo? `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` or maybe my python 2.7?